# Tweeting w/ media fails using Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, twitter, google-cloud-functions

My Firebase web project has been working for several months now. But on Sunday June 3, 2018, my application stopped sending tweets with media (images) attached. Before this, it was working for several months. I have not changed the failing code before the 3rd and I have even reverted to code that worked before that date but the app still fails :(

**SDK versions:**
I am using the most up to date versions of Firebase tools (3.18.6), and cloud functions (1.0.3). Along with twit (2.2.10) a javascript library for twitter api.
Do note my project was also working on older versions of the above including pre v1.0 cloud functions. Also note, I am still able to send regular text tweets just not ones with any media (image,gif,mp4).

This mainly relates to Twitter's API, but I cannot rule out something funky going on in Firebase's Node.js environment.

**How to reproduce:**
For simplicity, I will link to the code in a tutorial which I originally used when starting the project.

Setup a twitter account and retrieve all the necessary tokens as outlined in the tutorial. Then simply call the cloud function below and it will attempt to tweet the NASA image of the day.

The function is able to upload the picture to the twitter server and the response I get is expected:

```
{ media_id: 1004461244487643100,
  media_id_string: '1004461244487643136',
  media_key: '5_1004461244487643136',
  size: 92917,
  expires_after_secs: 86400,
  image: { image_type: 'image/jpeg', w: 960, h: 1318 } }
```

However, once it attempts to post the tweet with the media attached, I receive an error

> code 324: 'Unsupported raw media category'

which doesn't exist in Twitter's docs: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/response-codes.html

Now, Code 324 does exist but in Twitter's docs there is a different description:

> "The validation of media ids failed"

Which I have yet to receive. So my media id is valid, so something else is wrong? No where on the internet can I find someone with this exact error.

Link to tutorial code:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-and-deploy-a-multifunctional-twitter-bot-49e941bb3092

Javascript code that reproduces the issue:
**index.js

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const request = require('request');
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
const fs = require('fs');
const tmpDir = os.tmpdir(); // Ref to the temporary dir on worker machine

const Twit = require('twit');

const T = new Twit({
    consumer_key: 'your twitter key'
    ,consumer_secret: 'your twitter secret'
    ,access_token: 'your twitter token'
    ,access_token_secret: 'your twitter token secret'
});

exports.http_testMediaTweet = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

    function getPhoto() {
        const parameters = {
            url: 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod',
            qs: {
                api_key: 'DEMO_KEY'
            },
            encoding: 'binary'
        };
        request.get(parameters, (err, response, body) => {
            if (err) {console.log('err: ' + err)}
            body = JSON.parse(body);
            var f = path.join(tmpDir, 'nasa.jpg');
            saveFile(body, f);
        });
    }

    function saveFile(body, fileName) {
        const file = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
        request(body).pipe(file).on('close', err => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
          } else {
            console.log('Media saved! '+body.title)
            const descriptionText = body.title
            uploadMedia(descriptionText, fileName);
          }
        })
    }

    function uploadMedia(descriptionText, fileName) {
        const filePath = path.join(__dirname, `../${fileName}`)
        console.log(`uploadMedia: file PATH ${fileName}`)
        T.postMediaChunked({
          file_path: fileName
        }, (err, data, respone) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
          } else {
            console.log(data)
            const params = {
              status: descriptionText,
              media_ids: data.media_id_string
            }
            postStatus(params);
          }
        })
    }

    function postStatus(params) {
        T.post('statuses/update', params, (err, data, respone) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
          } else {
            console.log('Status posted!')
            res.status(200).send('success');
          }
        })
    }

    // Do thing
    getPhoto();

});
```

I was hoping to launch my app next week but this has become a major issue for me. I've tried everything I can think of and consulted the docs for Twitter and the js library but I seem to be doing everything right. Hopefully someone can shed some light on this, thanks.

Comment: I don't think Cloud Functions is going to be an issue here, but you should try running your code locally to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I didn't think this had to do w/ FB, but anyway, I ran it locally and got the same error.

I noticed that it told me Firebase Cloud Functions only supports Node.js v6.11.5 and that I am running 8.11.2.

Not sure if this makes any difference since Firebase controls the Node.js version correct?

Comment: The version of node is almost certainly not going to be an issue, unless you're trying to use javascript language features that are not available in newer versions of node.  And those would show different errors.

Comment: To improve the chances of getting help, isolate the program. Right now it seems that the problem is related to calling the twitter API, so reproduce the problem with only calling that API to rule out the chances of Firebase/Cloud Functions causing the issue. If you only need your `getPhoto` function to reproduce the problem, people will have to read less code, so more folks are likely to spend the time and see what's going on.

Comment: Hey Frank,
So I'm new to Node.js. What is an easier way of someone beig able to run this code? I assume you must run this in a Node.js env on a server no? I've tried plunking the js file in an html file and running the getPhoto() script locally but that does not work. Browsers can't load the modules the script requires.

Comment: @Doug I didn't think so but I wanted to rule out the environment as being the problem. I don't know any other way of running just the pertinent node.js code locally without a server and place for image to attach. So if its failing in FB-tools locally then something must be wrong with twitter api or library I'm using.